# If a number is not divisible by 2, 3 and 5, is enough to say that number is prime?

Tags: prime-numbers

I'm Computer Science student. Last day, my teacher say this to the class room: "If a number is not divisible by 2, 3, and 5, mean that number is prime. This because odd numbers are divisible by 3 or 5, and even numbers by 2".

That can be true? If it's or not, why?

Edit: I'm *not* an mathemathician. I necer belive the words of my teacher. I just want an professional clarify.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question   because I think it's one you should have been able to answer for yourself with a little thought about what "prime" means and a little arithmetic on numbers less than $100$. Did your teacher really say this seriously?

Comment: I swear. And make a little function in Python to "prove" this. 3 simple conditionals: if n mod {3, 2, 5} is not 0, then is prime.

Comment: You may be interested to read about the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes), a (*tedious*) way of finding all prime numbers within a certain range.  The claim that all numbers not divisible by $2,3,5$ are prime should be obviously false.  Those numbers which are not divisible by $2,3,5$ are simply those numbers still left in the sieve after the first three iterations of the algorithm, but there are still many more steps left to perform in the algorithm (*getting rid of all proper multiples of $7$, all proper multiples of $11$, etc...*).

Comment: For small counterexamples of numbers which are divisible by none of $2,3,5$ but which are not prime, consider $7\times 7 = 49, 7\times 11 = 77, 7\times 13 = 91, 11\times 11 = 121,\dots$

Comment: I wonder if this is a serious question. I don't believe that you really think any odd number is divisible by 3 or 5. I'm sure you know that $49=7^2$.

Comment: I would be interested in the sentence or two that your teacher said before or after those sentences. Perhaps you missed words like this: "Is the following true?" Even if not, a much, much better alternative (than coming to this web site) would have been to raise your hand and say "That is not true".

Comment: A correction to the statement that will make this true: "*If $x$ is a natural number between $2$ and $48$ and $x$ is not divisible by any of $2,3,5$ then $x$ is prime.*"  Once the upper bound on $x$ is removed however, this as mentioned is false.  We also needed the lower bound since $1$ is not considered a prime number.  (*Note: $x$ is a composite number if and only if there is some prime $p$ which divides $x$ such that $p\leq \lfloor \sqrt{x}\rfloor$, i.e. when searching for divisors, we need not look any further than the square root.*)

Comment: @Mark I never belive that. I always think that need to do a brute force algorithm to check all numbers above the possible prime. I only wanted to a real mathemathician clarify me.

Comment: And I just get -3 point. Ok. Thanks to all that response me with fundament.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$49$ is not divisible by any of those number but it is not a prime.

In general, take a prime number that is not $2,3,$ or $5$, consider $p^n$ where $n \ge 2$ works as a counter example.